# Large memory grant requests

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, memory-grant

I have one query with multiple execution plans, the memory granted to one plan is huge comparing to the 2nd one

[image]

[image]

based on this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/addressing-large-memory-grant-requests-from-optimized-nested-loops/

> The issue occurs when the outer table of the Nested Loop join has a
>   predicate that filters the result to a small input, but the batch sort
>   appears to be using an estimate for cardinality that is equivalent to
>   the entire outer table. This can result in a perceived excessive
>   memory grant which in a very concurrent server can have several
>   side-effects, like OOM conditions, memory pressure for plan cache
>   eviction, or unexpected RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE waits. We have seen how a
>   single query that match this pattern can actually get several GB’s of
>   granted memory on high-end machines (1TB+ RAM).
>
> One option until now would be to disable this feature globally using
>   Trace Flag 2340, as described in KB 2801413. However, in SQL Server
>   2016 RC0 we have changed the behavior to maintain the advantage of the
>   optimization, but now the max grant limit is based on the available
>   memory grant space. This improvement also translates into better
>   scalability, in the sense more queries can be executed with a smaller
>   memory footprint. We are looking at back porting this behavior to an
>   upcoming have ported this behavior to SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 2,
>   and as usual deliver added value to in-market versions.

This is exactly what I am seeing however I am using SQL Server 2016 Enterprise.

These are the execution plans

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ0mYAy0b

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJzutC1R-

My questions are

1. What is the reason for 2 execution plans?
2. The optimizer is using the top execution plan, I forced it to use the lower plan but after sometime it goes again to the top one, any reason for that?
3. How to fix this problem? This issue causes the application to crash (there were many `RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE` waits and the application become unresponsive)? Should I use the hint : `DISABLE_OPTIMIZED_NESTED_LOOP` or  `Trace Flag 2340`?

   **NOTE :** I checked the XML and both plans have  `NestedLoops Optimized="false"`

Answer (score 8):

> 1. What is the reason for 2 execution plans?

From the [sys.query_context_settings (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-context-settings-transact-sql) documentation:

> > There are a number of context settings available in SQL Server that influence the query semantics (defining the correct result of the query). The same query text compiled under different settings may produce different results (depending on the underlying data).

It seems most likely the same query text was submitted from sessions with different context settings. See also [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#querystore) by Erland Sommarskog.

> 2. The optimizer is using the top execution plan, I forced it to use the lower plan but after sometime it goes again to the top one, any reason for that?

Plans [will still recompile from time to time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn148262.aspx) based on the normal rules around changes to e.g. underlying objects, statistics, schema. Forcing a query store plan helps ensure the plan used will be at least *fundamentally similar* to the source plan, as [sys.query_store_plan (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-plan-transact-sql) notes:

> > Forcing mechanism *does not guarantee* that exactly this plan will be used for the query referenced by **query_id**. Plan forcing causes query to be compiled again and typically produces exactly the same or similar plan to the plan referenced by **plan_id**.

Each (re-)compilation may produce plans with different estimates (including memory grant) depending on any values in the query that are visible to the optimizer at the time of compilation. **A specific memory grant cannot be forced using query store or plan guides.**

> 3. How to fix this problem?

As Dan Guzman's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/189516) suggests, if the plan is very sensitive to specific parameter values, compiling a fresh plan on every execution using an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint may be the best practical solution.

That said, there are very few tools available to affect update-side execution plans, which can be complex where things like cascading foreign keys and indexed views are involved. If all else fails, you may find that an execution plan without sorts (to order rows in index key order) produces the best result. There is no documented way that I'm aware of to generate plans without these sorts, but you could try forcing the plan obtained with [undocumented trace flag 8795](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2013/01/26/optimizing-t-sql-queries-that-change-data.aspx) on.

You might also try a suitable `MAX_GRANT_PERCENT` [query hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query) or simply install (or make available to SQL Server) enough memory to handle your workload.

Answer (score 6):

Both the plans have `Optimized="false"` for the inner joins and have the same shape. I understand from the referenced blog post is that the memory grant issue, where the outer table estimate is used for the grant, applies only with `Optimized="true"`.  Also, these plans both have a row count of 1 for the nested loop outer table (table spool with deleted course id).

I suspect classic parameter sniffing. The estimated row count of the nested loop operator before the CoursePrerequisiteAssignment clustered index delete (cascaded delete?) is about 25 million in the top plan vs. 240 in the bottom one. That's probably what's driving the desired memory.

`OPTION(RECOMPILE)` might be the easiest and best solution. Separately, index tuning may help might avoid the full scan of the `CoursePrerequisiteAssignment` table every time a course is deleted.

Comment: I am getting the same problem if i  run it without a parameter   ex: id = 1234, also there are indexes on the CoursePrerequisiteAssignment

Comment: What is the nested loop estimated row count with the literal? What index on CoursePrerequisiteAssignment has CourseID as the first column?

Comment: It Returned 16000 rows, yes there is index with courseID first column. i just confused why the estmated row count for one is 25 million rows , this is the whole table. Is this a statistics problem ?

Comment: The estimated row count with a parameter or literal is based on the stats histogram so, if that stats are stale, the row count estimate may be wrong and affect the plan choice. Can you add DDL for the tables, constraints, and indexes to your question? I'm surprised the first plan (with the low estimate) is performing a scan of CoursePrerequisiteAssignment instead of seek a using the CourseID.